# Phantomjs - No such file or directory (what have I missed)

Tags: linux, debian, installation, phantomjs

May I ask for a little help with setting up phantomjs on a shared hosting server, please?

Let me run through what I have done and then ask my question.

Steps taken...

Used ‘Putty’ to check the architecture of my server, like so …

```
uname –m        // x86_64
cat /etc/issue  // Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l
```

I downloaded the 64bit version of ‘phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2’  from this page https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads

Placed that file in a folder on my server and ran the next command in Putty …

```
tar -jxvf phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

The files extracted and created a directory structure, seemingly without errors.
I changed to that that directory and ran ls. The phantomjs file was the only file listed.

I inspected the file with Putty …

```
file phantomjs
```

Which returned

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

Entering

```
echo "$PWD/phantomjs"
```

Gives me

```
/homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/cabs/mySite/phantom/bin/phantomjs
```

Next I tried

```
/homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/cabs/mySite/phantom/bin/phantomjs -–version
```

The result of which was the '**No such file or directory**' error ...

```
-bash: /homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/cabs/mySite/phantom/bin/: No such file or directory
```

However, if I just enter

```
/homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/cabs/mySite/phantom/bin/
```

then I get

```
/homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/cabs/mySite/phantom/bin/: Is a directory
```

May a linux novice ask for some pointers on where I have gone wrong. The readme file mentions being up and running in 5 minutes. So, I have that dreadful feeling I have missed something rather basic.

Thank you.

EDIT

permissions in the phantom directory

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 u387xx ftpusers 38346752 Oct 24  2014 phantomjs
```

permissions in the

```
/homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/cabs/mySite directory (specifically for the phantom folder)

drwxr-xr-x  7 u387xx ftpusers   4096 Jul 13 11:35 phantom
```

Edit

In Putty, whilst in the phantom/bin directory, if I run 
    ~/phantomjs

```
**/aHigherUpFolder**/homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/phantomjs: No such file or directory
```

Interesting as there is another directory further up the path now. However, trying ...

```
/aHigherUpFolder/homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/cabs/mySite/phantom/bin/phantomjs --version
```

Still leads me to a 'No such file ...' message.

Comment: Yes - I am using --version, just a typo. Will edit Q, thanks.

Comment: Since the error of `No Such File or Directory` seems to have the `bin/` directory and not the `phantomjs` in it, are you sure the path you tried to run is really correct?  Did you actually type out the directory name or copy/paste it from somewhere?  If there is an unprintable character it could throw things off and you wouldn't easily notice it after all.  If you're in the phantomjs directory can you run it with `./phantomjs`?

Comment: @ Eric Renouf Thanks for the pointer. I had been copying the path via Putty. Whilst in that 'bin' directory ./phantomjs returns '-bash: ./phantomjs: No such file or directory' again, I am using putty to fire that command. ls however shows that the file is in fact there. As a Windows man, I'm used to seeing file names with extensions ... should I expect a file name with extension in Linux? The file name is purely 'phantomjs' ie no extension.

Comment: what do you see when you do echo $PATH  on your server.

Comment: @KritiS ... ` /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/bin:/usr/local/msql/bin:/usr/games:.`

Comment: @Johnny it's not uncommon to have no extension in linux.  Could you do an `ls -l` in `/homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/cab/mySite/` and in the `phantom` subdirectory?   It would probably be best to edit your question to include that information too rather than putting it in a comment

Comment: @Eric Renouf  Will do - Need to pop out for an hour (my son is unwell), will then update Q with that information. Many thanks.

Comment: May it is not able to pick the path ,
you can try to export the path of phantomjs to the PATH variable , like
export $PATH=$PATH:/homepages/24/someNumber/htdocs/cabs/mySite/phantom/bin/phantomjs

To make it permanent you should add this in pofile file of the user as well on the server.
Try this and let me know if this works.

Comment: @KritiS I'll try your suggestion next. I have this feeling that it is the path that is the issue ... or more accurately my understanding of where the file is in the path structure.

Comment: I has got to be my understanding of the path as @Kritis suggestion results in ': No such file or directory' again.

Comment: Think I got it. Will update Q shortly after some testing. Clue .... Do as I did above with 32 bit version.

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact problem in reverse.  I accidentally downloaded the 32 bit build for a 64 bit box.  The underlying issue is discussed here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit

Basically, it's just a bad error message for a binary that's missing some essential libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I'm never sure if it's the right thing to do to answer your own question. However, I resent the amount of time I have spent on this and if I can offer someone else some clues, I think that is a good thing.

My goal with my original question was to produce the result ...

```
1.9.8
```

when entering

```
phantomjs -v
```

into Putty.

Basically, for whatever reason, I needed the 32bit version of the phantomjs file. While admittedly I am a novice with Linux I thought I had approached things sensibly and identified that I needed the 64bit version, but clearly not.

Out of desperation / frustration I downloaded phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-i686.tar.bz2 from the link in the question and followed the process above to extract the archive.

I changed directories to the phantomjs/bin folder and entered ...

```
phantomjs -v
```

Presto, majico ...

```
1.9.8
```

appeared in Putty.

I have no idea why the 64bit version would not work. Perhaps it was corrupted somehow, but I doubt it. I had thought of that and re-downloaded the file a number of times.

Thank you to those that made comments and helped me. I promise I actually learnt something from them. +1'd each of them.

EDIT

And just to confirm things with PHP, too ...

```
$output = exec($path . "phantomjs -v" . ' 2>&1');
var_dump($output);
```

Also produces the expected file version info.